# Is there an alternative to Maven Build Profiles in Grunt?

Tags: angularjs, maven, gruntjs

I am doing a project in AngularJS and I am using Grunt as my building tool. In Maven, there is a thing called Build profiles which allow us to have have more control over the build and keep the building process quite flexible. Information about the same can be found [HERE](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html). Is there any alternative in Grunt via which I can achieve this?

Comment: you simply create a task with parts (other tasks) you need and call it like `grunt sometask` -> http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [Gulp](https://jmperezperez.com/gulp-js/) or [Brunch](http://brunch.io/) as an option.

Comment: Do either of them have what I require?